# How to show an alert dialog when newly added data already exists

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to create a fitness app wherein I add exercises but the user should be restricted from adding the same exercise name. For example, in my database I already have an exercise name, "Push Up" and then later I am trying to add another exercise having the same exercise name which is, "Push Up". I want it to have that restriction in which it doesn't allow having the same exercise name and show an alert box saying, "It already exists."

Comment: If you want to show single line message then you should use Toast or Snack bar instead Dialog.

Comment: Not a problem. That's not my main problem here tho. Thanks

Comment: You need to make condition to check whether exercise is the same. if it's true then show dialog.

Comment: I think you should put in question some your code or more precise information about your database if you want us to tell you more precise answer.

Comment: I haven't started the code yet cause I'm having trouble on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a query on your database first and check if the same name already exists. You can return a boolean value so you can display a dialog box.

- First, check the entry on your database
- If the name already exists, then return true.

> if(isNameExist){
>      return dialogBox
>   else {
>     add exercise
>   }

Comment: That's giving me an idea on how to do it but doesn't really answer my question but thank you so much